# Regex and backslash

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex code like this.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println(validateAddress("Test C\O good:product"));
}

public static boolean validateAddress(String address) { 
return address.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9~`!@#$%^&*()_+={|}:;'<,>? -/\"\t\n\\[\\] .]*$");
 }
}
```

When i run this i get false as my expression does not accept \ character. I tried to include the \ but failed.

Can you please help as to how to include the \ character in my regex for validation ?

Thanks, 
Rakesh

Comment: First, you want to try against `"Test C\\O good:product"`. Second, to match a backslash, use `"\\\\"` in the pattern. And finally escape the `-` or put it at the end of the character class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you want to try against `"Test C\\O good:product"` as to define a backslash in the string literal you need to use `"\\"` (two backslashes). Second, to match a backslash, use `"\\\\"` in the pattern. And finally, escape the `-` or put it at the end of the character class.

See [Java demo](https://ideone.com/tAg5an):

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    System.out.println(validateAddress("Test C\\O good:product"));
}
public static boolean validateAddress(String address) { 
    return address.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9~`!@#$%^&*()_+={|}:;'<,>?\\\\ /\"\t\n\\[\\] .-]*$");
}
```

Comment: Thank you . That helped me.